# Tensorflow: no errors when size of output layer doesn't match size of expected results

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is more of a question than a problem. 
Let's say we have the following code/model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(10, input_shape=train_x.shape[1:], activation=activations.tanh))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation=activations.linear))
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=1e-3, decay=1e-5), loss=MSE)

model.fit(x=train_x, y=train_y, epochs=10, validation_data=(test_x, test_y))
```

The shape of train_x is (100,3). 
The shape of train_y is (100,2). 
The shape of test_x is (20,3). 
The shape of test_y is (20,2).

I would expect an error that the shape of the output layer doesn't match the shape of train_y elements - output layer has 1 neuron and the elements in train_y have 2 features (or whatever they are called).
There is no error, just the loss doesn't change much.
So my questions are: 
How does this work? 
Is it a bug or is there a reason for it to work like that? 
Am I doing something wrong?

I am using tensorflow 2.9.1 and python 3.8 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a bug. It is just simple [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
import tensorflow as tf

x1 = tf.random.normal((20, 2))
x2 = tf.random.normal((20, 1))

tf.keras.losses.MSE(x1, x2) # works with the help of broadcasting
```

Comment: Then, is my case just a corner case or does this have any useful applications in a similar context?

Comment: That is all up to you.